# Python typewriter function returning none when used within input?

Tags: python, function

```
    import random,sys,time,os 
os.system("cls")
def dialogue(passage):              # Function for dialogue to type slowly
     for letter in passage:
         sys.stdout.write(letter)
         sys.stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(0.1) 
name = input(dialogue("Hi, WHat is your name?"))
```

the input would pop up in the terminal as "Hi, WHat is your name?"NONE.
is there any way I can change this to just return the input without it stating NONE where the output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `return ''` to the end of the `dialogue` function:

```py
def dialogue(passage):
    for letter in passage:
         sys.stdout.write(letter)
         sys.stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(0.1) 
    return ''
         
name = input(dialogue("Hi, What is your name? "))
```